# React - Discord authentication with Auth0

Tags: reactjs, discord, auth0

I am using Auth0 to authenticate with discord.

The authentication works great with Google and returns a user class filled with information such as username and email. However, when using discord I am returned the below JSON which only has the nickname, name, and picture which are either empty or default.

```
{
  "nickname": "",
  "name": "",
  "picture": "https://cdn.auth0.com/avatars/default.png",
  "locale": "en-US",
  "updated_at": "2020-10-31T22:10:50.094Z",
  "sub": "oauth2|discord|[REMOVED JUST INCASE]"
}
```

Here is a picture of the popup login window :

[image: Discord authentication popup window]

Comment: Seems like you want the [email scope](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#shared-resources-oauth2-scopes)

Comment: Thanks, I've put a ticket in with Auth0 as their dashboard only allows the return of 'Identity' which still doesn't seem to be populated using their react Auth0 library.